# Three.js Passing Camera Look At Values to a Form

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to pass the values of my 3D scene to form field so ultimately I can save them in a database.  I can do this fine with most of the scene variables, but I have not figured it our for the camera.lookat.  Here are a few examples:

```
        document.getElementById('camera_rotation_x').value=camera.rotation.x;
        document.getElementById('group_position_x').value=group.position.x;
        document.getElementById('spotLight_position_x').value=spotLight.position.x;
        document.getElementById('spotLight_rotation_x').value=spotLight.rotation.x;
```

These all work fine.

For camera.lookat.x, however, it does not work:

```
        document.getElementById('camera_lookat_x').value=camera.lookat.x;
        document.getElementById('camera_lookat_y').value=camera.lookat.y;
        document.getElementById('camera_lookat_z').value=camera.lookat.z;
```

WHat am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered for me in another post.  The key is to use:

```
 controls.target
```

So here is my code for passing these variables:

```
 document.getElementById('controls_target_x').value=controls.target.x;
 document.getElementById('controls_target_y').value=controls.target.y;
 document.getElementById('controls_target_z').value=controls.target.z;
```

Answer (score 0):

.lookAt is a function used to set the rotation of the camera. It is **not** a variable with data.

However, if I were using .lookAt for keeping an object in view that was controlled by the user I could simply use those coordinates.

Ex: The user moves a THREE.Mesh ball around the environment using inputs

```
camera.lookAt(ball.position)
document.getElementById('camera_lookat_x').value = ball.position.x
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  We are probably on the right track.  This line produces an error: 

     camera.lookAt(ball.position);

I've tried it just before the render function, inside it and after it.

Comment: Unless you have an object named 'ball' with a position, that isn't going to do anything.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course.  My object is 'group.'  Now I understand what you are suggesting, but now what I'm looking for.  Here is my page and script: http://jay2.ligda.net/3Dtest/stackoverflow2.html

Comment: You can see how I'm passing the variables values of camera position to the form on the right.  As we rotate the object with the trackball controllers the values change.  Right clicking the object an dragging it appears to change the spot that the camera is looking.  I want to be able to pass those values to the form as well.  It is not changing the object position or those values would update in the form (this has been tested).  I don't know how to grab those lookat values to pass them to the form.  Thanks if you can help.